# Toggle not working on the correct element

Tags: javascript

The issue with this code is that regardless of which icon I click on, it is always the first question that drops down, none of the others do. Can anyone help?
I get that `document.querySelector()` will always return the first element, but if I use `document.querySelectorAll()` I get a node list and an error saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined"

[image: Image of what I have built, a set of questions that you can click on the plus and minus signs in order to dropdown the answers.]

```js
let openQuestion = () => {
  let answer

  answer = document.querySelector('.answer')
  console.log(answer)


  if (answer.style.display === "block") {

    answer.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(answer.style.display)
    console.log('f')

  } else {

    answer.style.display = 'block';
    console.log(answer.style.display)
    console.log('a')
  }

}
```

```html
<div class='question-container'>
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>Can I return my order?</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion()">
  </div>
  <div class="answer" id="default-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>How much will it cost to ship my item?</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="minus-sign" class="toggle-icon" onclick="openQuestion()">
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.answer')` will always return the **first element that matches in your document, and only that element**.

Comment: May you add some example HTML?

Comment: @connexo yes, I understand that but if i use document.querySelectorAll('.answer') it returns a node list and I get this error "app.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined"

Comment: @RMP1992 inspect what is returned with that `querySelectorAll` - it's an array so it won't have a `display` property on it, only the elements within the array will have it.

Comment: @maxshuty The issue is that it doesn't have a `style` property. If it doesn't have a `style` property, obviously you cannot access `style.display` either.

Comment: You should not edit suggested solutions into your question. For future readers, this question becomes useless otherwise because they can no longer see where you were coming from. That being said, your snippet with these edits worked as expected. I am going to roll back your edits for the reason explained.

Comment: Please stop editing your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important note on all the 3 examples below:

You must make sure that the Javascript code shown is executed only **after** your HTML containing the questions and answers is parsed by the browser. This can either be achieved by putting the `<script>`-tag that holds the Javascript right before the closing body tag `</body>`, or by wrapping the JS code from the examples in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener (which runs as soon as the browser has parsed all the HTML in the page) like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* the JS from the examples here */
});
```

I don't know your HTML, but I'll create a minimal example of what needs to be done:

```js
// first get a nodelist of all the questions
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

// then iterate over that list
for (const question of questions) {
  // and add a click listener to each of them
  question.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // find the answer that belongs to the question clicked
    const answerToQuestion = question.nextElementSibling;
    // then toggle its visibility using the hidden attribute
    answerToQuestion.toggleAttribute('hidden');
  })
}
```

```css
.answer { color: green; margin-left: 15px; }
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">What is the meaning of life?</div>
  <div class="answer" hidden>42.</div>
  <div class="question">Is there life in meaning?</div>
  <div class="answer" hidden>Woot?</div>
  <div class="question">Foo?</div>
  <div class="answer" hidden>Bar.</div>
</div>
```

Edit: You have now added your HTML, which is actually very similar to the example I picked. You should easily be able to adjust the code by yourself now.

As an alternative, you can also do the hiding/showing based on CSS:

```js
// first get a nodelist of all the questions
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

// then iterate over that list
for (const question of questions) {
  // and add a click listener to each of them
  question.addEventListener('click', () => {
    question.classList.toggle('show-answer');
  })
}
```

```css
/* answers by default have display: none */
.answer { color: green; margin-left: 15px; display: none; }

/* this changes if the answer is an adjacent sibling 
   of an element that has the css class "show-answer" */
.show-answer+.answer { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question">What is the meaning of life?</div>
  <div class="answer">42.</div>
  <div class="question">Is there life in meaning?</div>
  <div class="answer">Woot?</div>
  <div class="question">Foo?</div>
  <div class="answer">Bar.</div>
</div>
```

Please note that both the method to find the corresponding answer via JS (`question.nextSiblingElement`), and the method to find it using a CSS selector (`.show-answer+.answer`) depend on the current HTML structure.

If e.g. your HTML would have the answers as child elements of the question itself, for the first example the method to find the answer changes to

```
question.querySelector('.answer')
```

and the CSS selector from the second example changes to

```
.show-answer .answer
```

Just to show you that it works as intended for your HTML as well (only removed the images and added `hidden` attribute to the answers):

```js
// first get a nodelist of all the questions
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions');

// then iterate over that list
for (const question of questions) {
  // and add a click listener to each of them
  question.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // find the answer that belongs to the question clicked
    const answerToQuestion = question.nextElementSibling;
    // then toggle its visibility using the hidden attribute
    answerToQuestion.toggleAttribute('hidden');
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="question-container">
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>Can I return my order?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" hidden>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
  <div class="questions">
    <h3>How much will it cost to ship my item?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="answer" hidden>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this is my code 
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question-container');

for (const question of questions) {
    question.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        const answer = question.querySelector('.answer');
        answer.toggleAttribute('hidden');
        
    })
}

However the hidden attribute is not being removed

Comment: For your HTML, it has to be `const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions');`. You have chosen to find all `.question-container` elements, not the `.questions` elements.

Comment: Also in your HTML, the answers are adjacent siblings of the questions. Use nextElementSibling instead of querySelector.

Comment: i have the changes but its still not working

Comment: You see in my answer I added the code along your HTML (with some changes mentioned). And you see it works.

Comment: Make sure the Javascript shown is loaded only after your HTML. This can be achieved if you put the `script` tag right before the end of the body `</body>`. Alternatively and even better, put the whole JS in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener like this: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, function() { /* the code here */ });`

Comment: Its ALIVE, its working, thank you so much. I added DOMContentLoaded

Comment: If it runs here for you, but not on your own machine at home, the reason will be what I prefaced my answer with now.

Answer (score -3):

Add an id on each questions in you html and in your js

```
let openQuestion = (id) => {
let answer

answer = document.getElementById(id)
...
```

Comment: That is nothing short of making matters **worse**.